# Pagination in CouchDB?

Tags: pagination, couchdb

How would I go about implementation the queries required for pagination?

Basically, when page 1 is requested, get the first 5 entries. For page 2, get the next 5 and so on.

I plan to use this via the couchdb-python module, but that shouldn't make any difference to the implementation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The [CouchDB Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/) has a good discussion of pagination, including lots of sample code, here: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/recipes.html#pagination
Here's their algorithm:

- Request `rows_per_page + 1` rows from the view
- Display `rows_per_page` rows, store last row as `next_startkey`
- As page information, keep `startkey` and `next_startkey`
- Use the `next_*` values to create the next link, and use the others to create the previous link

N.B.: The proper way to fetch pages in CouchDB is by specifying a starting key, not a starting index like you might think. But how do you know what key to start the 2nd page on? The clever solution: "Instead of requesting 10 rows for a page, you request 11 rows, but display only 10 and use the values in the 11th row as the startkey for the next page."

If you expect to have multiple documents emit identical keys, you'll need to use `startdocid` in addition to `startkey` to paginate correctly. The reason is that `startkey` alone will no longer be sufficient to uniquely identify a row. Those parameters are useless if you don't provide a `startkey`. In fact, CouchDB will first look at the `startkey` parameter, then it will use the `startdocid` parameter to further redefine the beginning of the range if multiple potential staring rows have the same key but different document IDs. Same thing for the `enddocid`.

Comment: The problem with this aproach is you cannot really click previous multiple times, only once. You either have to manually index ALL possible first-in-page when you go to the next pages or you only can go back 1 page and then you dont have any information whatsoever to go previous another page.

Comment: For those that stumble here and also run into @for3st's dilemma, the natural characteristics of an array help remedy this issue. By `push()`ing the previous page start `_id` into array you can easily `pop()` the array `_id` when you click previous. At most all you have to do is keep track of is an array of integers.

Answer (score 13):

The CouchDB [HTTP View API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API) gives plenty of scope to do paging efficiently.

The simplest method would use `startkey` and `count`.  Count is the max number of entries CouchDB will return for that view request, something that is up to your design, and startkey is where you want CouchDB to start.  When you request the view it will also tell you how many entries there are, allowing you to calculate how many pages there will be if you want to show that to users.

So the first request would not specify a startkey, just the count for the number of entries you want to show.  You can then note the key of the last entry returned and use that as the start key for the next page.  In this simple form, you will get an overlap, where the last entry of one page is the first of the next.  If this is not desirable it is trivial to simply not display the last entry of the page.

A simpler method of doing this is to use the skip parameter to work out the starting document for the page, however this method should be used with caution.  The skip parameter simply causes the internal engine to not return entries that it is iterating over.  While this gives the desired behaviour it is much slower than finding the first document for the page by key.  The more documents that are skipped, the slower the request will be.

Comment: Aha! From that page you linked: the count parameter can be combined with the "skip=number of rows to skip". Perfect.

Comment: I've added the above info to your answer (for my reference if nothing else), hope you don't mind!

Comment: I edited it again.  Using skip is not a good way of doing this is most cases.

Comment: Ah, I thought this may be the case.. Is there a quicker way to find the x-th key?

Comment: No, to find the n-th entry you need to iterate over the index tree because you don't know how many entries a branch in the tree has.  You can find a specific key much faster.

Comment: looking at the link you posted, I see that there is no "count" option. There is a "limit" option instead. Maybe it was changed?

Comment: skip is actually now pretty efficient (since COUCHDB-1076 was fixed) and it's the only way to safely iterate in the general case. There are edge cases in the startkey_docid pagination method which will prevent it progressing (e.g. if each document emits multiple times such that all rows in a page contains the same key / docid).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have came up with so far - to get the ids of all posts, then retrieve the actual items for the first x number of IDs..

It's not terribly efficient, but more so than retrieving all the posts, then throwing most of the away. That said, to my surprise, it seemed to run quite quickly - I ran the `posthelper.page()` method 100 times and it took about 0.5 seconds.

I didn't want to post this in the actual question, so it wouldn't influence the answers as much - here's the code:

```
allPostsUuid = """
function(doc) {
if(doc.type == 'post'){
    emit(doc._id, null);
}
}
"""

class PostsHelper:
    def __init__(self):
        server = Server(config.dbhost)
        db = server[config.dbname]
        return db


    def _getPostByUuid(self, uuid):
        return self.db.get(uuid)

    def page(self, number = 1):
        number -= 1 # start at zero offset
        start = number * config.perPage
        end = start + config.perPage

        allUuids = [
            x.key for x in self.db.query(allPostsUuid)
        ]
        ret = [
            self._getPostByUuid(x) for x in allUuids[start : end]
        ]

        if len(ret) == 0:
            raise Error404("Invalid page (%s results)" % (len(allUuids)))
        else:
            return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

- Here below is the recursive way I found :

  Take two variables

```
  var lastOffset = 0; var counter = 0;

  function someRecursive(lastOffset,counter) {

  queryView(db, whereClause).then(result => {
      var rows_per_page = 5; 

//formula below 
var page = Math.floor((lastOffset == 0 ? 0: (result.offset - lastOffset) +

  (rows_per_page * counter)) /  rows_per_page) + 1;

   var skip = page * rows_per_page;
  if (somerecursionexitcondition) {
                   counter = lastOffset == 0 ? lastOffset: counter + 1;
                   lastOffset =result.offset;
              someRecursive(lastOffset, counter).then(result => {
                               resolve();

                           });
  });

  }
```