# translate this mysql into a couchdb view?

Tags: mysql, view, couchdb, translate

I'm quite new with couchdb and I want to create a view based on a simple mysql statement.
I found this documentation: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/cookbook.html but there are sadly not all use cases included.

My MySQL-Statement:

```
SELECT `title`, `id`, `author`, `date`, `text` FROM `news` WHERE `date`<=NOW() AND `author`='22' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 20,10;
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a view with the following map function.

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.author, doc.date], {
            "title": doc.title, 
            "author": doc.author, 
            "date": doc.date, 
            "text": doc.text});
}
```

Now you can query the view using the following URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/dbname/_design/design_doc_name/_view/viewname?startkey=[22, "2010-11-12T10:20:30"]&endkey=[22, {}]&descending=true&skip=20&limit=10
```

The date in the start key must be the current datetime. There is no way to emulate `NOW()` in couchdb.

A view in couchdb is just a list of key-value pairs sorted by key and it provides a way to access a range of that list. You need to design your view such that you can get the results that you need using a range query.

Comment: As an interesting point here is that you implemented `LIMIT 20`, and not `LIMIT 20,10`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how is possible to make this offset at the limit?

Comment: You can't (at least, not with reasonable performance). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312163/pagination-in-couchdb

Comment: heuri, you can pass `skip=20`. Corrected the url in my response.