# Faceted search with geo-index using CouchDB

Tags: lucene, couchdb, geospatial

CouchDB offers the ability to perform faceted search via Lucene. I would like to perform a faceted search where one of the facets is geospatial (e.g. within 30km of a lat/long).

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: Perhaps not a direct answer, but have you considered Solr? It offers a full suite of geo queries.

Comment: I understand Solr is not compatible with CouchDB, but if this cannot be done in Couch then I wil consider other techs. MongoDB, for example has geo' out of the box I think...

Comment: HTH http://stackoverflow.com/a/6435585/272861

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [GeoCouch](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch) it's a fork of CouchDB that supports geospatial queries/indexes.

Comment: Will GeoCouch permit me to perform searches that combine both geo and non-geo elements like so (pseudo query): `find all items with a name of "fred", an age of "25", who live less than 30km from London`?

Comment: Good question, I'm not able to comment as I've not worked with GeoCouch before. (sorry, was hoping to just point you in this direction)