# couchdb pagination

Tags: pagination, couchdb

I need to use pagination in my application. How can i achieve this with couchdb. I have looked up for online resources, they  direct us to use startkey and limit with couchdb for pagination.

Could someone post a simple example please, it would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You may check out this [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312163/pagination-in-couchdb).

There are multiple options to implement pagination over views, the most effective way is by following the algorithm mentioned on [CouchDB guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/recipes.html#fast).

If you are looking for a working example, you may check out [this library](http://www.lightcouch.org/), it's in Java.