# Given a record and order conditions, find record(s) after or before

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For example, you have a list of items, sorted by priority. You have 10,000 items! If you are showing the user a single item, how do you provide buttons for the user to see the previous item or the next item (what are these items)?

You could pass the item's position to the item page and use OFFSET in your SQL query. The downside of this, apart from having to pass a number that may change, is that the database cannot jump to the offset; it has to read every record until it reaches, say, the 9001st record. This is slow. Having searched for a solution, I could not find one, so I wrote [order_query](https://github.com/glebm/order_query).

[order_query](https://github.com/glebm/order_query) uses the same ORDER BY query, but also includes a WHERE clause that excludes records before (for next) or after (for prev) the current one.

Here is an example of what the criteria could look like (using the gem above):

```
p = Issue.find(31).relative_order_by_query(Issue.visible, 
      [[:priority, %w(high medium low)],
       [:valid_votes_count, :desc, sql: '(votes - suspicious_votes)'],
       [:updated_at, :desc],
       [:id, :desc]])

p.before     #=> ActiveRecord::Relation<...>
p.previous   #=> Issue<...>
p.position   #=> 5
p.next       #=> Issue<...>
p.after      #=> ActiveRecord::Relation<...>
```

Have I just reinvented the wheel here? I am very interested in other approaches of doing this on the backend.

Internally this gem builds a query that depends on the current record's order values and looks like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE    
x0 OR
y0 AND (x1 OR
        y1 AND (x2 OR
                y2 AND ...))
ORDER BY ...
LIMIT 1
```

Where `x` correspond to `>` / `<` terms, and `y` to `=` terms (for resolving ties), per order criterion.

Example query from the test suite log:

```
-- Current record: priority='high' (votes - suspicious_votes)=4 updated_at='2014-03-19 10:23:18.671039' id=9
SELECT  "issues".* FROM "issues"  WHERE 
  ("issues"."priority" IN ('medium','low') OR 
   "issues"."priority" = 'high' AND (
       (votes - suspicious_votes) < 4 OR 
       (votes - suspicious_votes) = 4 AND (
           "issues"."updated_at" < '2014-03-19 10:23:18.671039' OR 
           "issues"."updated_at" = '2014-03-19 10:23:18.671039' AND 
           "issues"."id" < 9)))   
ORDER BY 
  "issues"."priority"='high' DESC, 
  "issues"."priority"='medium' DESC, 
  "issues"."priority"='low' DESC, 
  (votes - suspicious_votes) DESC, 
  "issues"."updated_at" DESC, 
  "issues"."id" DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand it, but couldn't you use some sort of pagination with a limit of 1 per page?

Comment: Pagination would not be able to do this efficiently (load 1 record, without using `OFFSET`)

Comment: Specifically kaminari and will_paginate do not do this efficiently. order_query, on the other hand, uses an approach that maybe can be used for pagination as well.

Comment: If your goal is to provide a better user experience why not try to use AJAX? You could even prefetch the next, prev result while the user is still reading the current page.

Comment: I would still need to make that database query.

Comment: you might find the pagination approaches for couchdb interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312163/pagination-in-couchdb

Comment: @glebm Can you explain in detail your issues on sending items position and offset ?

Comment: @shiva What if I land on the result without passing through search (where the offset comes from), e.g. if I land on a result from Google? What if the collection changes mid-browsing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an alternative approach, and it uses a construct from the [SQL '92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) standard (Predicates 209), the row values constructor comparison predicate:

> Let Rx and Ry be the two *row value constructors* of the *comparison predicate* and let RXi and RYi be the i-th *row value constructor elements* of Rx and Ry, respectively. "Rx *comp op*  Ry" is true, false, or unknown as follows:
>
> - "x = Ry" is true if and only if RXi = RYi for all i.
> - "x <> Ry" is true if and only if RXi <> RYi for some i.
> - "x < Ry" is true if and only if RXi = RYi for all i < n and RXn < RYn for some n.
> - "x > Ry" is true if and only if RXi = RYi for all i < n and RXn > RYn for some n.

I found an example [in this article](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page#sb-row-values) by [Markus Winand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312881/markus-winand). Row value constructor comparison predicate can be used like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM sales
 WHERE (sale_date, sale_id) < (?, ?)
 ORDER BY sale_date DESC, sale_id DESC
```

This is roughly equivalent to this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM sales
 WHERE sale_date < ? OR (sale_date = ? AND sale_id < ?)
 ORDER BY sale_date DESC, sale_id DESC
```

The first caveat is that to use this directly all the order components have to be in the same direction, otherwise more fiddling is required. The other being that, despite being standard, row values comparison predicates are not supported by most databases (does work on postgres).