# Make pagination with pouchdb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, pagination, pouchdb

I want to make pagination with `pouchdb`.

See code to get all data

```
function getAllData() {
     if (!_data) {
         return $q.when(_db.allDocs({ include_docs: true})) 
             .then(function(docs) {
                 _data = docs.rows.map(function(row) {
                     return row.doc;
                 });
             });
     } else {
         return $q.when(_data);
     }
 };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pagination in CouchDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312163/pagination-in-couchdb)

Comment: Also a little of research will yield this https://pouchdb.com/2014/04/14/pagination-strategies-with-pouchdb.html